# FFMPEG Wipe transition one layer over another

Tags: ffmpeg

How to reveal one layer over another with a wipe transition using FFMPEG?

[image]

NOTE: this is not a slide transition. The top image stays in one position but is gradually revealed over time.

I'd like a technique that can work for top layers with or without transparency and for images, videos or dynamically created sources, like `showwavespic`.

I tried making a mask animation like so:

[image]

but `alphamerge` doesn't work as I expected it to and I can't find a `blend` mode that works with this type of mask.

EDIT: The `xfade` filter was suggested but it doesn't seem to work with when source has transparency. It renders  transparent areas black. Example with transparent source:

[image]

But `xfade` renders this:

[image]

Comment: See the xfade filter - https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade

Comment: @Gyan Unfortunately `xfade` doesn't work when the top layer has transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i flower.jpg -t 5 -loop 1 -i gear.png -filter_complex "[0]format=rgb24,drawbox=thickness=fill,split[black][black2];[black2]negate[white];[black][white]xfade=transition=wiperight:duration=1:offset=0[alf];[0][1]overlay=format=auto[ovr];[ovr][alf]alphamerge[fg];[0][fg]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

1. *format* filter will allow drawbox to make true black color. Otherwise it may make a semi-transparent overlay as in the example GIF where you can barely see though the gear (I didn't notice when I initially made it). If you want YUV instead of RGB use `yuv444p` for example instead of `rgb24`.
2. *drawbox* covers `flower.jpg` with black. Alternatively you can use the *color* (and optionally *scale2ref*) filters. This is a lazy way to make a black image the same size as the input.
3. *split* filter makes a copy of the black image and *negate* filter makes the copy white.
4. *xfade* makes an animated alpha mask from the black and white images.
5. *alphamerge* adds the alpha mask to the output from *overlay*.
6. The resulting overlay with alpha is overlaid over `flower.jpg`.

Also see

- [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) for a gallery of transition effects.

Comment: It seems that `xfade` doesn't work with transparency. Transparent areas in the top layer are rendered black.

Comment: @logan That's exactly what I need. Bottom layer to show through transparent areas of top layer. Question updated with image examples. Any alternative methods to xfade?

Comment: @logan It looks like `crop` doesn't accept the `t` property in the `out_w` expression. Is that what you had in mind?